# VB.NET Clear DataTable then Fill AFTER Successfully Getting New Data

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, ado.net, tableadapter

I currently use a TableAdapter to fill() a typed datatable in a typed dataset. ClearBeforeFill is set to True as the underlying data is different each time. The problem is that in the case the database is unreachable, the old data gets cleared before it knows. I want the old data to stay in the datatable (and subsequently stay displayed) in the case an error occurs retrieving from the database. Ideally, I'd still use a tableAdapter and the GetData() method instead of the Fill() method but I can't seem to figure out how to replace the current datatable with the one returned by GetData(). Tables.Remove() then Tables.Add() doesn't seem to work. Below code gives an error: "'table' argument cannot be null." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: table"

```
Dim TempTbl As DS_ERecord.DT_spRefreshAndSelectStepConnectorMonitorDataTable
TempTbl = TAi_spRefreshAndSelectStepConnectorMonitor.GetData(ForceRefresh, CmbMonitorView.SelectedValue)
DSi_ERecord.Tables.Remove(DSi_ERecord.DT_spRefreshAndSelectStepConnectorMonitor)
DSi_ERecord.Tables.Add(TempTbl)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to test the connection to the database is available before doing the Fill with ClearBeforeFill set?  And is there a reason not to simply call the DataTable.Clear() method rather than removing and adding tables to the DataSet?

Comment: Bind whatever control you are using to display to a BindingSource and only set the DataSource of that BindingSource to your Data after a successful fill.

Comment: Ya, i just tried the remove and add based on what I found online. I will try these two ideas. Thanks!